# Значение строки

Tags: php, laravel

Не могу понять что означает этa строка?

```
$oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
```

Что означают эти знаки ? и :

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.php

Comment: Если в сессии есть элемент 'cart', то вернуть его, иначе null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это тернарный оператор.

Аналогичная запись:

```
if( Session::has('cart') ){
   $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
} else {
  $oldCart = null;
}
```